# How do I permanently remove the Wolfram Desktop folder?

Tags: bugs, mac-os-x, configuration

Wolfram Desktop creates a "Wolfram Desktop" folder in my Documents folder on macOS, in violation of [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW6). I can delete it but it keeps coming back each time I launch Desktop.

How do I *permanently* remove the Wolfram Desktop folder?